# How to declare friend user-defined literal operator within template class?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, language-lawyer, user-defined-literals

It is unclear why the code below does not compile with GCC g++ 4.7 telling the following:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -fPIC test.cpp 
test.cpp:11:45: error: ‘B operator"" _b(const char*, size_t)’ has invalid argument list
```

If class C is declared non-template then it compiles fine.

```
#include <cstddef>
struct B{};

B operator+(B, B) { return B(); }
B operator"" _b(const char *, size_t) { return B(); }

template<typename T>
class C
{
    friend B operator+(B, B);
    friend B operator"" _b(const char *, size_t);
};

int main() { return 0; }
```

What is wrong with this code? Or is it a compiler bug?

Comment: Clang [accepts it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5a348201f75b6e9), I'd say compiler bug in GCC.

Comment: Behaviour is still the same in g++4.10 20140613

Comment: Just added a bug for it.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or is it a compiler bug?

This code is correct, as the signature of the operator function is explicitly allowed by the standard - see §13.5.8/3. 
So it is a GCC-Bug.

Comment: It's a bug.  Thanks.  g++ accepts literal operator friends for non-template classes but not for *template* classes.  clang++ accepts this.  Registered as [PR C++/61648] (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61648).